# equality between the index between field with $p^{n}$ elements and $ \mathbb{F}_{p}$ and n?

Tags: finite-fields, extension-field

can someone explain this?

$ \left[\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}:\mathbb{F}_{p}\right]=n $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|\Bbb F_p|=p\;,\;\;|\Bbb F_n^n|=p^n$$

amd since any element in the latter is a *unique* linear combination of some elements of it and scalars from the former, it must be that those *some elements* are exactly $\,n\,$ in number.